# Using Moment.tz to convert to timezone

Tags: javascript, reactjs, momentjs, moment-timezone

I have the following code

```js
const timeInTz = moment.tz('2022-01-01 21:00', 'America/New_York').utc().format('HH:mm');
alert(timeInTz);
```

I'm trying to convert from eastern time to utc and then only get the time in the output date, but the result is not a UTC date but actually eastern time. The code is not converting the date from one timezone to another. Can someone please help?

Comment: It's working for me. Have you installed the relevant data? Here's a working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dLykqr78/)

Comment: moment(date, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm').tz('America/Los_Angeles').utc().format('HH:mm') is not working for me. It prints the timezone in my local timezone.

Comment: Why did you change the syntax, your original call is working

Comment: Expanded [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/15w8crtf/)

Comment: It’s still not working for me. I switched to the version of tz that you are using and it doesn’t work. Can you use the latest version?

Comment: updated to the latest version, still working... [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/15w8crtf/1/)

Comment: @pilchard I have another question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70698629/how-to-get-the-next-sunday-in-a-users-timezone-using-moment-timezone. You were so helpful with this question. Can you help me out with the second one? Much appreciated!